# Lossless video editing on Linux?

Tags: linux, video, mpeg

Is there a simple Linux program that allows for video editing without reencoding? All I want to do is extract the video between time T1 and T2 and write that to a new file.

All my searches are turning up empty. I'm considering trying emacs -- copying and pasting blobs of binary.

Does a better solution exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is mpeg2 you can use gopchop

```
gopchop - Fast, lossless cuts-only editor for MPEG2 video files
```

I think avidemux can do this as well

```
avidemux - a free video editor - GTK version
```

basically you would make your cuts and then save the output file and tell it to 'copy' rather than re-encode anything...

from the command line you can use mencoder or ffmpeg the same way.  Specify the start and end times, but use 'copy' for the codecs.. something like..

```
ffmpeg -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss xxx -t xxx ...
```

Comment: I think the ability to cut at arbitrary frame boundaries might be encoding-specific.

Comment: I've found `ffmpeg` usually pukes a non-monotone timestamps error when using the `-vcodec copy`/`-acodec copy` options. Avidemux is very buggy; you can get it do this if you're patient enough to try enough combinations of settings, and are willing to re-encode the audio to PCM.